# How to verify existence of elements in page using Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, verify

I'm trying to figure out a way to see if an element is existing/not existing on a page.

This is what I have so far.

However, if an element is not existing, an exception will be thrown, and the script will stop.

Could anyone help me find a better way to do this?

```
//Checking navbar links
        System.out.println("=======================");
        System.out.println("Navbar link checks");
    //Checking for Web link element in Nav bar
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a"))!= null){
            System.out.println("Web link in Navbar is Present");
            }else{
            System.out.println("Web link in Navbar is Absent");
            }
    //Checking for Images link element in Nav bar
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a"))!= null){
            System.out.println("Images link in Navbar is Present");
            }else{
            System.out.println("Images link in Navbar is Absent");
            }
    //Checking for News link element in Nav bar
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a"))!= null){
            System.out.println("News link in Navbar is Present");
            }else{
            System.out.println("News link in Navbar is Absent");
            }
    //Checking for Videos link element in Nav bar
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a"))!= null){
            System.out.println("Videos link in Navbar is Present");
            }else{
            System.out.println("News link in Navbar is Absent");
            }
    //Checking for Maps link element in Nav bar
           if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[5]/a"))!= null){
            System.out.println("Maps link in Navbar is Present");
            }else{
            System.out.println("Maps link in Navbar is Absent");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couple of different methods.  For this, I'd probably recommend using `findElements`:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a"))!= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid exeptions you can simply write your own helper that will handle [NoSuchElementException](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) and return `null` instead :

```
public class Helper {
    private static final WebDriver driver;
    public static WebElement findElement(By locator) {
        try {
            return driver.findElement(locator);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException notFound) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // initialize Helper with your driver on startup
    public static init(WebDriver yourDriver) {
        driver = yourDriver;
    }
}
```

Then just call it in your code :

```
//Checking for Web link element in Nav barl
WebElement element = Helper.findElement(By.xpath("my/complex/xpath"));
if(element == null) {
    System.out.println("My Element is Absent");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a really dumb question, but where would the helper class be placed? Outside the "main" function, within the same java file?

Comment: You could create standalone Helper.java and put that class in it, then you can access helper methods all across your project.

Comment: Hmm. I think my whole thought process is wrong. 

In the webpage that I am attempting to automate testing for, there is a navigation bar with an id called "topnav".

Depending on the version of the page I am looking at, the navigation bar will have different navigation links.

How would I be able to iterate through that navigation bar, to output all the navigational links found within in it?

Comment: You could start by getting WebElement navBar = Helper.findElement(By.id("topnav")); and then search for the elements within the navBar  :`navBar.findElement`. You have to implement the logic yourself. You can ask a separate question on SO. I only tried to address the issue of terminating your java code due to exception, that you originally asked.

Comment: I understand kiruwka. Thanks for your assistance. I'll try and figure it out now.

Comment: BTW, to complete the Helper class I sketched, you would need to pass a `driver` to it, for instance when you initialize your test. I will add some  code for it.